# how to create multiple button in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have create one custom cell and I want to create multiple button in that cell in ios. I have created  multiple buttons in cell but I have problem on selection.I want to select first button by default.Check image for better understanding

**Image**

[image]

Comment: It all depends on how you write your data source. You can have an array/dictionary of bools to set the buttons, and load your tableview accordingly.

Comment: I have created buttons but i want to selection on this button.

Answer (score 0):

I would make this a collectionView that allows single selection.  This is because you are representing sizes/dimensions and they come in notoriously different and arbitrary scales (0-14, XS-XL, 28-44, etc).  If you make a it a collection view it very easy to handle arbitrary size scales by modifying the collection view datasource methods.  If you make this a fixed set of buttons and someone comes along and changes the size scale, you have a problem.